# How to handle a decibel meter type component/widget?

Tags: android, audio, microphone, decibel

I'd like to be able to have some sort of volume panel looking something like :

|||||||||||||||||||||

Where the lines highlight according to how loud/quiet the sound is according to decibels. Is there a built in Android component to handle this, or does anyone have any ideas as to how I could handle this?

Comment: you'd have to record the sound from the mic, and get the level somehow

Comment: @njzk2 Do you have any idea how I could go about getting the decibel values from a recorded sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be to use a Rating Bar and override the android:numStars value to be the number of bars you want. Then, create a drawable that will replace the star images with bars. Really hope this helps.

Best of luck.

Comment: Awesome. Looking forward to hearing your results!

Comment: This worked, I created images of the empty and filled bars in Photoshop and used them to create a custom `RatingBar`.